# I am trying to return a True or false if a given directory contains ".exe"

Tags: c#, linq, filesystems

I have this code to return the true/false;

```
public static bool HasExecutable(string path)
    {
        var exts = "*.exe";
        if (path.AsDirectory().Exists) return true;
        if( path.AsDirectory().GetFiles(exts).Any(i => path.Contains(exts))) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

My out put is a error that stops my program, Am i missing some logic here?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: It is 
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'c:\program files (x86)\notepad++'.
 .

Comment: @Aominè it has a error when using the i element, Can not convert from fileInfo. to string

Answer (score 2):

You can just enumerate the directory with pattern matching and use `Any` extension method.

```
public static bool HasExecutable(string path)
    {
        var exts = "*.exe";
        return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, exts).Any();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
if (path.AsDirectory().Exists) return true;
```

returns `true` if the directory itself exists. Instead, it should return `false` if the directory does not exist:

```
if (!path.AsDirectory().Exists) return false;
```

The LINQ portion has a problem, too: `Contains` call on the path will never return `true` for `"*.exe"` string because paths are not allowed to have wildcard characters. However, you don't need a condition at all, because `GetFiles` has done the filtering for you:

```
return path.AsDirectory().GetFiles(exts).Any();
```

You can fold both conditions into a single statement:

```
return path.AsDirectory().Exists
    && path.AsDirectory().GetFiles(exts).Any();
```

Comment: Hi @dasblinkenlight thank you for the code but following the changes with my test cases i am returning a false value instead of true invoked method with @"c:\program files (x86)\notepad++" /// expected true returned false

Comment: @d.Freeze That's odd, there's nothing special about the implementation that's essentially a one-line call of system methods. Please check your test cases to ensure that the expected result is correct (exe file must be in the directory itself, not in one of its sub-directories, in order for this code to work).

Comment: here is a test case // if (true.ToString() != Practice.HasExecutable(@"c:\program files (x86)\notepad++").ToString())
            {
                TestFailures.Add(Tuple.Create(@"c:\program files (x86)\notepad++".ToString(),true.ToString(),Practice.HasExecutable(@"c:\program files (x86)\notepad++").ToString()));
            } ///  I have added a return path.AsDirectory().GetFiles(exts, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any(); to search all directorys, still returns the wrong value

Comment: @d.Freeze Why do you keep using `ToString()` on `bool` data type? To debug what's going on, add some printouts - for example, print the results that you get from `path.AsDirectory().GetFiles(exts)` before calling `Any()` and returning.

Comment: @dasblinkenlinght My test case was stoping when i checked if  the path exsited so i changed the code to read 
` var exts = "*.exe";
            if (!path.AsDirectory().Exists) return true;
            return path.AsDirectory()
.GetFiles(exts, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any();

Comment: @d.Freeze It should be `if (!path.AsDirectory().Exists) return false;`, not `true`.